# how do i make my dojo mobile div zoomable?

Tags: html, mobile, dojo, zooming, dojox.mobile

I already have a dojo scrollable view div with a object inside. when i view the div i want that div to be zoomable with the pinch to zoom gesture, how do i do that?

```
<div id="divSvgView" dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" style="background-color: #d0d0d0;">
        <!--foreground-->
        <div style="float:right; width:30px; height:30px;position: absolute; z-index:10; right: 20px; top: 20px"><a href="javascript:goToLastNodeDiv()"><img class="closeIcon" src="img/close-icon.png" /></a></div>
        <!--background-->
        <div style="width:100%; position: absolute; z-index:2"><object type="application/xhtml+xml" id="svgObject" data="" style="width:100%; height:97%;margin:1%;"></object></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in. Since your div doesn't contain Dojo widgets but pure HTML, I'm not sure you really need to use dojox.mobile's ScrollableView. Instead, you could rely on a DIV with overflow:scroll (supported on various recent browsers; see for instance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow and many hits here on stackoverflow), and implement the pinch to zoom gesture independently on Dojox Mobile using guidance that you can find over the web including on stackoverflow ([Pinch to zoom with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802176/pinch-to-zoom-with-css3) is just an example).