# How do i add a pinch zoom to an image using phonegap?

Tags: image, phonegap-build, pinchzoom

I need help on putting a pinch zoom on a image.
I'm using phone gap.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked in past.

Please refer to [Pinch to zoom with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802176/pinch-to-zoom-with-css3)

Or

[PhoneGap pinchzoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061456/phonegap-pinchzoom)

Many more topics already discussed then above.

If you have questions specific to device or behavior please mention it and will be glad to help.